# SSIS variable in case when statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, business-intelligence

It's possible to use SSIS variable in case when statement in Data Flow?

I have to implement something like:

```
select
...
case when Data >= ? then NULL else Data end DataName,
...
from ...
where filter = ?
```

where "?" is iterator, which I get from Foreach Loop (over 100 iteration). Whole query have over than 4000 chars.

I use SQL Server 2008R2. I have also to load this query to different server.

Comment: That case does not make much sense to me. Can you add why you do this?

Comment: @juergend I can't show DataName for specific date (filter) if it's later than Data (business logic). This is only part of my whole query.

Comment: Presumably it works okay with just the parameter in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: (Also, the way I'd do this is to simply select `data`, then add a Derived Column in the dataflow to do this calculation for me, producing a new column called DataName with the value you need. Mapping parameters anywhere other than the WHERE clause in a data flow is often a pain. You can use parameters easily in Derived Columns.)

Comment: Yes you can use a variable in a CASE expression.   But I don't know what you're thinking you can do when you talk about an iterator.